# Coin toss: number of heads / number of tosses converges to 1/2

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

Imagine throwing a coin N times, let x be the number of heads. Show that $\frac{x}{N} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$, as N increases.

So I know that a coin toss follows the binomial distribution with $p = q = \frac 12$ (we have a fair coin).

So then the probability of getting x heads after n tosses would be ${n}\choose{x}$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$.. but I don't know how to use that to solve my question...
The only other thing I could think of was that the expected value of the binomial distribution is equal to np. So then dividing this by n gives p... but this seems to trivial to be right.

Comment: You can invoke the strong law of large numbers here. The weak convergence is not too hard to show (try showing that $P(x/N \in [0.5-\epsilon,0.5+\epsilon]) \to 1\; \forall \epsilon > 0$)